# Difference between using ng-model and custom attribute for 2 way binding on custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

When building a custom form input directive should i use ng-model or my own custom my-val attribute.

The outcome I want is 2 way binding so that changing the input updates the model on the $scope and changing the $scope updates the form input.

I understand that if I "require": "ngModel" in my directive then I get passed the ngModelController whereas using myVal will be a simple property.

Comment: there are other issues that need to be considered ... isolated scope and validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-model` serves two main purposes:

1. DOM-agnostic abstraction layer that provides hooks for other directives (custom and built-in) to validate, format or parse the value
2. integration with `form` directive to set `$dirty`/`$pristine` and `$valid`/`$invalid` flags

So, you could definitely have a custom two-way bound attribute, but then you lose out on using directives like `ng-required` or `ng-change`, and other custom directives that support `ng-model` model.